# List View With Sliding Menu Fragemnt

Tags: android

Update:

Just so you know, when i try importing the project I end up with more errors than i can count thus why i'm here trying to figure it out. My sliding was working fine, it was just adding a listmenu that was throwing me off. Thank you for being patient with me.

I didn't change the main so here it is anyways:

```
package com.projectcaruso.nfp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I tired to import his code into mine as the MenuFragment.java

```
package com.projectcaruso.nfp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class SampleItem {
        public String tag;
        public int iconRes;
        public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
            this.tag = tag; 
            this.iconRes = iconRes;
        }
    }

    public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

        public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
            icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

The list.xml is blank
the activity_main.xml is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your current code. I suggest you look at the sample given in Sliding menu (`SlidingFragmentActivity`,`SlidingListActivity`) examples 
You CAN NOT have two Activities running at the same time. Sliding menu is in the back, but it is managed by the front activity. What you are looking for is a Fragment.

Update:

[Activity](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/LeftAndRightActivity.java), [ListFragment](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/SampleListFragment.java) samples may help.

Basiclly what you need is

```
// set the content view
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.fragment_menu);
```

Should be a blank layout. Then the important part:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
```

If you do super.onCreateView() that will just do nothing or crash like what you having now. I strongly recommend you looking at the two samples in the link.

Comment: Check out that gragment and let me know what you think